# Is there a free tool that is like a regexp wizard?

Tags: regex

Does there exist a free Windows software program that will help you generate regular expressions using a wizard?

I'm not exactly sure what I am looking for but I am not looking for a regexp evaluator. What I need is a calculator/wizard to help me learn how reg expressions work, while not knowing all the syntax details (until i have the experience of course).

Comment: Basically you want a free version of RegexBuddy?

Comment: I'm wondering if what you're asking is really sensible. Regex is a complex and expressive way of defining goals that natural language would struggle with. ie, to explain `a\s+([Dd]og|[Cc]at)\s+eats\s+(a*\s+|\s*)\1` you would need an explanation like "'a' followed by whitespace followed by 'dog' or 'cat' with an optional initial capital followed by whitespace then 'eats' followed by whitespace with an optional 'a' followed by whitespace followed by whatever the second word was. I'm not sure it would be very easy to convert or use such explanations programmically. Better to just read a tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is a good free tool. It just needs email registration, but it's free. The developer of that tool also wrote [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx) which you can use to follow along. It's included in the help file of Expresso.

RegexBuddy is **not** free, but seems to have a helpful UI and a cool debugger. Take a look at [the demos](http://www.regexbuddy.com/demo.html).

Comment: thanks. that was what I am looking for.   I like the sample input text it comes with.  lots of good stuff to play with.    the runner up for me was the gSkinner tool that Ross mentions.

Answer (score 3):

gSkinner has a good [online tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) which has a desktop version too.

Comment: i like this one a lot.  im choosing to use Expresso but this is one that I will bookmark. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) won't quite do what you want, but it does have an info panel that explains your regex in plain English and it shows you when you've got a match in your test string.

Answer (score 0):

A tool is handy for testing purposes, but if your ultimate goal is to actually learn regex, get [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/): *the* book w.r.t. regex-es.

A good on-line resource is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

[ReguLazy](http://osherove.com/blog/2006/7/9/introducing-regulazy-point-click-regular-expression.html) is a neat idea for this sort of thing. It's a pretty simple way to build and test a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Expresso is just the best for me and it's free.....